# App Current Shutdown closing window prompting

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, .net-4.5

I have a wpf project which has couple of windows, whne i navigate from one window to other i just  hide one window and create instance of other if not created already, otherwise just make it visible

in all windows there is window closing event handler

```
 private void Window_Closing_1(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
         {

        string message = "You are trying to close window " + this.Name + " .Are you sure?";
        string caption = "Exit";
        MessageBoxButton buttons = MessageBoxButton.YesNo;
        MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Question;
        if (MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, icon) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            App.Current.Shutdown();

        }
        else
        {
         MessageBox.Show("Closing aborted");

        }
    }
```

but problem is this event is there in every window so when i close it lots of other prompt from other window which are invisible also show up. Is there a way to avoid other pronpts if i close in only one window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a static method in another class to handle closing of forms.

```
public class X 
{
    private static bool isClosingHandled = false;

    public static void HandleClose()
    {
        //// app closing logic
        isClosingHandled = true;
    }
}

private void Window_Closing_1(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    X.HandleClose();   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried in App.xaml to add Exit attibute?

it will be a better solution since you will only have to write this confirmation exit code just once. about window name you could cast sender to window in order to find out its name

Comment: what is that ? I am sorry i am new to WPF. Do i need to write closing window logic in  private void Application_Exit_1(object sender, ExitEventArgs e) in app.xaml ?

Comment: window name is not important